# c++ How to pass iterator pointer to function that expects the object by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, pass-by-reference

So in my body code I make an iterator to work through a list of pointers to Point objects and I need to be able to pass that pointer to the set_point_one function.

```
list<Point*>::iterator it = on.begin();
l->set_point_one(*it);
```

The set_point_one function is overloaded like this:

```
void set_point_one(const double x, const double y, const double z) { one_.set_xyz(x, y, z); }
void set_point_one(Point &p) { one_.set_xyz(p.get_x(), p.get_y(), p.get_z()); } //trying to get it to use this one
```

When I run this code, I get the error:

```
./facet.cc:79:20: error: no matching member function for call to 'set_point_one'
            l->set_point_one(*it);                             //set both end points of the line to the point
            ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./line.cc:21:10: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'value_type' (aka 'Point *') to 'Point &' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with
  *
void set_point_one(Point &p) { one_.set_xyz(p.get_x(), p.get_y(), p.get_z()); }
     ^
./line.cc:20:10: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
void set_point_one(const double x, const double y, const double z) { one_.set_xyz(x, y, z); }         ^
```

I've tried playing with dereferencing a bit with no luck. Is there something obvious I'm missing or is the only way for me to get it working to further overload the function so it also explicitly takes a pointer to the object?

Thanks in advance,

Max

Comment: Are you sure you need a list of pointers? A vector is generally better and a container of objects as well.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you post how you're populating and emptying that `list`? I'm not trying to be offensive, but given the question you're asking, there's a fairly good chance you might be doing something wrong there. Unless you've got a good reason to use a `list`, I'd follow @chris' advice and change it to a `vector<Point>` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm always open to suggestions. I've always just used lists myself. What are the pro's of using vectors

Comment: @MaxRahm, Vectors have contiguous memory, which immediately puts them in the realm of being used with something that wants an array. There has also been a lot of testing on performance between the two and vectors win in a lot of cases. The advice is to use a vector unless you've profiled and shown that you need something else, or need something for semantics, such as a map for its arbitrary key type.

Comment: @MaxRahm And changing from `list<Point*>` to a `list<Point>` or `vector<Point>` means you don't need to dynamically allocate the `Point` objects or make sure you `delete` them before removing them from the container. This is an error prone process, especially when you factor in exceptions. And to add to what chris said, `vector`s are very CPU cache friendly because of the contiguous storage. One of the few reasons I can think of to prefer a `list` would be if you needed to store iterators (pointers) to the elements in the container, and needed these to remain valid as you added new elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*it` dereferences the iterator, returning the object, it points. In your case - `Point*`.

As your function takes `Point&`, you need to dereference it one more time. Meaning

```
// not mandatory -v---v
l->set_point_one(*(*it));
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "not mandatory" comment?  Are you referring to the parentheses being optional? If so, which is the better style?

Comment: @User - yes, the parentheses are optional. Better style - the one, that you like more OR if the current project/company you're working for has a special requirement for the style of similar cases. I'd avoid the parentheses, added them just to make my answer a bit more clear what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following sample help :

```
using namespace std ;

void test(int* &p)
{
    cout << *p << endl ;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int*> lp ;
    int *p1,*p2 ;
    p1 = new int(100201)  ;
    p2 = new int(12345)  ;

    lp.push_back(p1) ;
    lp.push_back(p2) ;
    std::list<int*>::iterator it = lp.begin();
    test(*it) ;
}
```